# Microsoft Sharepoint and Snowflake integrations and automations

Tags: sharepoint, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to integrate the Sharepoint site with Snowflake. Read the data from SharePoint files and upload it to the snowflake.

We are not looking to use a separate integration tool.

Answer (score 0):

One option that i can think of is loading these files into external stage object, external stage object is Blob Storage In case of Azure Cloud Service Or  S3 Bucket in Case of Azure Cloud Service  and then using Snowpipe to load continuously using these files into Snowflake. This is link you can refer to know more about Snowpipe.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html
Other option i can think of is , You would have to write dot net code in Share point to read the data files in sharepoint and using Snowflake Connector/Driver to Connect to Snowflake and load the data into it.